# Best way to show to a user a list of quotes sent by other users

Tags: website-design, user-expectation, information-architecture, info-visualisation, information-design

I have a **website (not native mobile app)** where users can send their quotes about a specific service. Let's say User X sends a request to find someone that can fix his TV, so... dozens of other users who can fix that TV send their quotes; in the end, User X can see a whole list of quotes sent by the other users. Before the question, there are some things to take into account:

1. Each user who sends a quote, has qualifications with stars and comments from previous customers.
2. Each quote has some attributes such as price, proposal, and how much time will take to finish the service.

Now my question is, what is the best way to show a list with this info? Right now, I have it like this:

1. Each quote is inside a box, this box has ALL the information about this quote: price, who sent the quote, star rating; in a modal box, the references or comments, date of completion, and maybe the largest text is the proposal, and of course, contact info of who sent the quote. (This could open in an accordion.)

[image]

**NOTE: Take into account that the user can have 12, 20, 100, or any quantity of quotes, each box represents a different quote**

2. But I'm thinking that maybe there is too much information in a box, and in that box we should only show basic information and a button with "More Info" and redirect the user to another page with ALL the information about the quote.

[image]

The disadvantage that I'm seeing of option 2 is that the user has to come back to the quote list, and click on a quote, see the info, and come back to the list, and like this so on.

What do you think? What would be the better option? Or maybe there are other ways to show that info?

Comment: This question is way too broad as it stands, but it sounds like you have an interesting problem to address. Can you share any wireframes or sketches to help us understand what might not be working? Without that, we'll just start a discussion about general info architecture principles, which has been addressed here many times before.

Comment: In fact, [I just answered this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/87855/21857) earlier today that may provide some insight for your project.

Comment: @plainclothes I dont have wireframes rigth now, but let me make them and I edit the question with the wireframe, although I think I'll do it with an accordion as someone recommend me.

Comment: @plainclothes I have edited my question with the wireframes... Sorry for the draw, im not expert in wirframes.

Comment: Very helpful. If I get a chance today, I'll post some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend showing this in an accordion/drawer style list that will expand to allow the user to see more information when they click on the quote line.

Can the quote document open up in a modal so they can preview it and then just click to close it and return to the same page?

Comment: I was thinking the same, maybe in the modal I can show the califications of the seller, next thing is think how organize the information in the accordion, but this would be in other topic.